# Choppy display on a mid-2015 MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, display, hardware-failure, macbook-pro

The screen flashes as picturedy, then returns to normal. Red blocks are post photograph redacting sensitive information.

Recently managed to grab a photo as it sat this way an abnormally long period of time. Seems to be occurring more frequently. Terribly unsure of how to describe this so as to google similar problems. Searching for suggestions on cause / how to describe this / solution, etc.

[image]

Some answers to questions posted in the comments:

- **How long occurring?** Uncertain. Screen has always cleared quickly until this time.
- **Did anything happen to physically precipitate this?** No.
- **What happens if you hook it to an external display?** I have 2 hooked up (1) HDMI (2) TB3 to DP. No effect on them.
- **What if you closed the lid to the MacBook right when this happens and open it up again?** Don’t have to. Clears on its own.

Comment: Sorry you are experiencing this. But how long has this been going on? Did it just suddenly appear? Did anything happen to physically precipitate this? Like dropping the MacBook in some way? What happens if you hook it to an external display? What if you closed the lid to the MacBook right when this happens and open it up again? Does it clear things up? There’s a similar post on the [Apple SE site here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/352939/40457). I would recommend downloading [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) to clear caches on the MacBook and see if that helps.

Comment: * How long occurring? --> Uncertain.  Screen has always cleared quickly until this time.  * Did anything happen to physically precipitate this? --> no  * What happens if you hook it to an external display? --> I have 2 hooked up (1) HDMI (2) TB3 to DP.  No effect upon them.  * What if you closed the lid to the MacBook right when this happens and open it up again?--> don't have to.  Clears on its own.   Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks! If it is happening sporadically, I would recommend  using [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) to clear macOS caches and see of that helps. If not, try zapping the PRAM [as explained here](https://support.apple.com/en-gu/HT201255). If none of that works, my guess based on your answers is the internal display connector is loose. Something getting progressively bad would show signs as you describe. Opening up the MacBook and reconnecting the internal display connector might help. Worst case? Display itself is busted. Your choice on how to handle that.